# mod rewrite rewriting but not redirecting

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, redirect, opencart

I have some RewriteRules in .htaccess file for an OpenCart installation.

The default OpenCart .htaccess rules are all present but I need to redirect some outdated links from an old site.  The rules I have a working in that they do ultimately display the correct page but they fail to redirect, i.e., the browser bar link remains unchanged although the correct page is served.

```
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^product/old-link$ http://example.com/new-link/[R=301,L]

RewriteBase /

# If using subdirectory, update RewriteBase /
# Store URL: yourstore.com/shop
# Update to: RewriteBase /shop/

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

What I would like is for the browser to redirect as I would expect so when someone visits:

`example.com/product/old-link` they are then redirected to: `example.com/new-link`

But it doesn't work.  Instead `example.com/new-link` is served up but `example.com/product/old-link` remains in the browser.  It was my understanding the the [R] flag should take care of this.

Comment: Are you really missing the whitespace before `[R=301,L]`? I'm not sure if it matters, though I would expect it to matter...

Comment: That was it!  Thanks Michael